# Email to image in ckeditor?

Tags: entities, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a module to convert emails links to an image in the body field to prevent spam.

The closer I found is this one but it's for drupal 6 and I needed for D7: http://drupal.org/project/email2image

Since I'm using ckeditor maybe there is plugin for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at

http://drupal.org/project/textimage

> Textimage adds text to image functionality using GD2 and Freetype, enabling users to create crisp images on the fly for use as theme objects, headings or limitless other possibilities.

Comment: thanks, have you tried with ckeditor?

Comment: Not in ckeditor directly but you could use the url method as mentioned in the site or create a module to add a filter.